# How to make sure that NJsonSchema only includes required fields?

Tags: c#, njsonschema

I'm using [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema) v2.6 for generating the JSON Schema for the following class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Message", Namespace = "")]
public class AMessageModel
{
    [DataMember]
    internal Guid MessageId { get; set; }

    internal DateTime MessageDate { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Message", Namespace = "")]
public class AddUserMessage : AMessageModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FistName { get; set; }

    [Range(2, 5)]
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The generated JSON Schema:

```
        {
          "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
          "type": "object",
          "typeName": "AddFitnessHubAccountMessage",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "AccountName": {
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            },
            "FistName": {
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            },
            "LastName": {
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            },
            "Email": {
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            },
            "Password": {
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            }
          },
          "allOf": [
            {
              "type": "object",
              "typeName": "AMessageModel",
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "properties": {
                "MessageId": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "guid"
                },
                "MessageDate": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "date-time"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

Even though the MessageDate property is not marked as a DataMember, it is always included in the schema, also the generated schema includes two schema paths when it should only include one, it seems that the parser is not flattening the properties.

**UPDATE**

This fixes the issue with multiple schema paths being created

```
new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings
{
    FlattenInheritanceHierarchy = true
}
```

GitHub Issue: https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/issues/53

Comment: This is a bug in the current implementation... Ill fix that soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of the library [NJsonSchema](http://njsonschema.org).

**Ignored properties**

There was a bug in the library and now (v2.7+) property ignore works as follows:

> A property is ignored when either
>
> 1. The property is marked with the `JsonIgnoreAttribute` property
> 2. The class has an `DataContractAttribute` attribute and the property has no `DataMemberAttribute` and no `JsonPropertyAttribute`

https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/wiki/JsonSchemaGenerator

**Flatten inheritance hierarchy**

As you already found out, you can flatten the inheritance hierarchy via the `FlattenInheritanceHierarchy` setting...

The library is mainly used for code generation, and thus the inheritance is usually needed.

Comment: I will give it a try later on. Thanks a lot for the quick fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Since NJsonSchema has a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json, have you tried this from the Newtonsoft.Json documentation?

[Conditional Property Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm)

> To conditionally serialize a property, add a method that returns
>   boolean with the same name as the property and then prefix the method
>   name with ShouldSerialize. The result of the method determines whether
>   the property is serialized. If the method returns true then the
>   property will be serialized, if it returns false then the property
>   will be skipped.

Comment: It's a good one but that didn't fix it. Newtonsoft.Json also works with DataContracts but I gave it a try still and the result is the same. Maybe they just to a Type scanning and include all the properties...Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The JSON Schema generation is actually not a serialization process and thus not implemented in Json.NET but in NJsonSchema. The process only uses reflection to build up the JSON Schema...